# How does QSignalMapper work?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, slot, qsignalmapper

After my post here : [Associate signal and slot to a qcheckbox create dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257789/associate-signal-and-slot-to-a-qcheckbox-create-dynamically/24258067#comment37473258_24258067) I need to associate :

• The signal `clicked()` when I click on a `qCheckBox` to my function `cliqueCheckBox(QTableWidget *monTab, int ligne, QCheckBox *pCheckBox)`

To do so, I have to use `QSignalMapper`, after two hours of trying to understand how it works, I can't have a good result, here's the code I make, this is obviously wrong :

```
 QSignalMapper *m_sigmapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
 QObject::connect(pCheckBox, SIGNAL(mapped(QTableWidget*,int, QCheckBox*)), pCheckBox, SIGNAL(clicked()));
 QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(cliqueCheckBox(QTableWidget *monTab, int ligne, QCheckBox *pCheckBox)));

 m_sigmapper->setMapping(pCheckBox, (monTab,ligne, pCheckBox));
 QObject::connect(m_sigmapper, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(cliqueCheckBox(QTableWidget *monTab, int ligne, QCheckBox *pCheckBox)));
```

Can you explain to me, how `QSignalMapper` works ? I don't really understand what to associate with :(

Comment: why do you have to use `QSignalMapper`? any particular reason? this can be done easily with direct connection

Comment: Well, in the other post, they explain to me that a signal can't be connect to a slot with more parameter, and the signal clicked() have no parameters. Also I need those 3 parameters.

Comment: true, slot can have equal or less number of parameters than corresponding signal. but you can write a slot which takes no parameter, then call the actual slot/method from this with required parameter.

Comment: Yes but how can I pass him the 3 parameters : QTableWidget *monTab, int ligne, QCheckBox *pCheckBox ? If you read the other post you will I have hundred of qCheckBox, so I can't use pointers.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil For understanding how `QSignalMapper` works, here is a [good example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html) for you to start with.

Comment: @Tay2510 I already read this, but thanks, maybe I'm stupid, but it doesn't help me so much.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil I think you need QSignalMapper because you have many widgets which emit a signal and you want to know in the destination slot which one has emitted the signal.

Comment: @Nejat Yes I think too, but I don't really understand how to call the connect function, what is the goal of setMapping, ...

Comment: @EvansBelloeil That's the greatest example I've ever found and it explains `QSignalMapper` step by step in details. You just need to ruminate it and it takes time. I think you are just a little bit too urgent on solving this problem; it has nothing to do with being stupid or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`QSignalMapper` class collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal. So you can have one like:

```
QSignalMapper * mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
QObject::connect(mapper,SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget *)),this,SLOT(mySlot(QWidget *)));
```

For each of your buttons you can connect the `clicked()` signal to the `map()` slot of `QSignalMapper` and add a mapping using setMapping so that when `clicked()` is signaled from a button, the signal `mapped(QWidget *)` is emitted:

```
QPushButton * but = new QPushButton(this);

QObject::connect(but, SIGNAL(clicked()),mapper,SLOT(map()));
mapper->setMapping(but, but);
```

This way whenever you click a button, the `mapped(QWidget *)` signal of the mapper is emitted containing the widget as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you ! It works, but how can i put 3 parameters ? Is this possible ? Because it seems I only can put 1 because of mapped(QWidget *)

Comment: It is not possible to have more than one parameter. You can have the other widget as class members and access them in the slot.

Comment: What do you mean class member ? If I can't pass it as a parameter how can I find ?

Comment: I mean you can put pointers to your widgets in your class .h file as private. Then you can access them.

Comment: No. Global variables should not be used in object oriented programming. You can simply have access to the pointer of your widgets in your class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55764/discussion-between-evans-belloeil-and-nejat).

Answer (score 14):

First I will explain you how `QSignalMapper` works. Then I will explain you why you don't need it.

**How `QSignalMapper` works:**

Create s `QSignalMapper`. Lets assume that you want to assign an integer value to each checkbox, so every time you click on any checkbox, you will get a signal with the integer value assigned to it.

Connect the mapper signal to your SLOT, that you will implement:

```
connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(yourSlot(int)));
```

Now you can write slot, that will take integer argument. The argument will be different for each checkbox you have.

While you create checkboxes, for each checkbox you need to do following:

```
mapper->setMapping(checkBox, integerValueForThisCheckbox);
connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()));
```

From now on, every time you click on a checkbox, it will emit `clicked()` signal to the `QSignalMapper`, which will then map it to the assigned integer value and will emit `mapped()` signal. You connected to that `mapped()` signal, so `yourSlot(int)` will be called with the proper integer value.

Instead of integers, you can assign `QString`, `QWidget*` or `QObject*` (see Qt documentation).

This is how `QSignalMapper` work.

**You don't need it:**

- The `QTableWidget *monTab` is the single object, it doesn't change. Keep it as a class member field and use it from your slot function.
- The `QCheckBox *pCheckBox` - you can get it by casting `sender()` to `QCheckBox*`.

Like this:

```
void supervision::yourSlot()
{
    QCheckBox* pCheckBox = qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(sender());
    if (!pCheckBox) // this is just a safety check
        return;
}
```

The `sender()` function is from `QObject`, which you do inherit from, so you have access to it.

- The `int linge` (it's a line number, right?) - when you create checkboxes, you can store pointers to that checkboxes in `QList` class field and use it from your slot function find out which line is it, like this:

In class declaration:

```
private:
    QList<QCheckBox*> checkboxes;
```

When creating checkboxes:

```
QCheckBox* cb = new QCheckBox();
checkboxes << cb;
```

In your slot function:

```
void supervision::yourSlot()
{
    QCheckBox* pCheckBox = qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(sender());
    if (!pCheckBox) // this is just a safety check
        return;

    int linge = checkboxes.indexOf(pCheckBox);
}
```

If you want, you can skip that `QList` and use `QSignalMapper` and assign lines to checkboxes using mapper. That's just a matter of what you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that is very good and very complete. My problem is that there's several QTableWidget, so if I don't use QSignalMapper, my way to access to this QTableWidget is to use parent() on the QCheckBox I think. It seems like i'm force to use lots of tricks, and it may cause problem, because my code has to be flexible. So I will try with QSignalMapper at first. Could you provides me more detail so about it  ? (I'm sorry this is very hard for me to understand )